# Set of Polynomials to determine Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the general procedure for proving a set of polynomials is a basis for a vector space of polynomials? I understand how to find if the set of the polynomials is linearly independent and how to find the rank of the matrix resulting from the polynomials, but I have trouble making the connection between the rank and the span (if there is one) and proving that the polynomials indeed span the vector space.

For example, consider the set of polynomials {$x,1+x,x-x^2$}. Determine if these polynomials form a basis for $\mathcal{P}_2$. I found that they are linearly independent and the rank of the resulting matrix of the polynomials is 3 and that the dimension of $\mathcal{P}_n$ is 3, but where do I go from there to make the connection that the set is a basis for $\mathcal{P}_n$?

Comment: If you've found that they are linearly independent, you just need to show that you can write any polynomial of degree 2 $a+bx+cx^2$ as a linear combination of the elements in your basis.

i.e. $a(x) + b(1+x) + c(x-x^2)=ax+b+bx+cx-cx^2=b+(a+b+c)x+(-c)x^2$

Comment: @jl00 I still seem to be a bit confused; if you want to show that an arbitrary 2 degree polynomial $s_3 x^2 + s_2 x + s_1$, then you can show that $s_3 = -c$ and $s_1 = b$ and $s_2 = a+b+c = a+s_1 - s_3$, but how do you proceed from there? Is this not a constraint on $s_2$?